# How to decipher number code in PHP

Tags: php, string, numbers

I'm using the PHP function `email()` to send a small text, but this text has foreign font family and on my email I get something like this:

> & #4304; & #4321; & #4307;& #4304;& #4321;& #4307

I'm using font `Acad Nusx Geo`. How can I get normal text on my email? Is there any function or not?

Comment: Nothing at all to do with fonts, but charset is important: something like `echo html_entity_decode("&#4304; &#4321; &#4307;&#4304;&#4321;&#4307", ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');`

Answer (score -1):

You might like to use the [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/de/function.htmlentities.php) function to convert the given strings into html-entities